# Change y labels in a python sklearn partial dependence plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to change the ylabel from a partial dependence plot from "partial dependence" to "failure probability".

This post is similar to [change x labels in a python sklearn partial dependence plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397337/change-x-labels-in-a-python-sklearn-partial-dependence-plot) but the solution did not work and apparently the y_axis is hard coded in the function ([line 740 of the current `partial_dependence.py` source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/inspection/_plot/partial_dependence.py#L740)).

Comment: Please post the relevant code *here*, not in external repos; see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plots share the y-axis, so calling `set_ylabel` on an axis may not set the correct one.

Here's how it could be solved:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
pdp = plot_partial_dependence(
    clf, X_train, features, feature_names=names, n_jobs=3, ax=ax, grid_resolution=50
)
pdp.axes_[0][0].set_ylabel("Failure Probability")
```

Full code:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependence
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cal_housing = fetch_california_housing()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    cal_housing.data, cal_housing.target, test_size=0.2, random_state=1
)
names = cal_housing.feature_names
clf = GradientBoostingRegressor(
    n_estimators=100, max_depth=4, learning_rate=0.1, loss="huber", random_state=1
)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

features = [0, 5, 1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
pdp = plot_partial_dependence(
    clf, X_train, features, feature_names=names, n_jobs=3, ax=ax, grid_resolution=50
)
pdp.axes_[0][0].set_ylabel("Failure Probability")

fig.suptitle(
    "Partial dependence of house value on nonlocation features\n"
    "for the California housing dataset"
)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Output image, showing the y-axis is labeled 'Failure Probability']